# Which Stackexchange site should I use to ask questions about the Windows OS?

Tags: discussion, windows

I have some questions regarding Windows 7 and I would like to find a website that's an appropriate place for me to ask them and since I have had a good experience with stackexchange I thought I would stick to it if possible.

Comment: Please try [su].

Answer (score 14):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/), as declared by Jokerdino. That will probably be the best place for those.